# What is the function of __construct() in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, construct

I work with CodeIgniter framework and I'm new to this. In the following code, `__construct()` function is used for loading a model.

- Why do I need to use `__construct()`?
- When should I use this function?
- What is `parent::__construct()`?

Code

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('example');
}
```

Comment: I think parent construct is getting axed in the next version for models.

Answer (score 3):

The construct function lets you use things over the entire class. 
This way you don't have to load the model/language/settings in every method.

Say you have a model and language that you want to load for that class, you can do this in the constructor. If you have for example an email method in the class and only use email in that class, you dont have to set this in the constructor but in the method. This way it doesn't get loaded unneeded for all the other methods that dont use it.

```
    class Contact extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('contact_model', 'contact');
      }

      public function index(){
        $data['contact'] = $this->contact->getContact();
        $this->load->view('contact', $data);
      }

      public function send_mail(){
        /* Mail configuration - ONLY USED HERE */
        $config = array('protocol' => 'mail',
                    'wordwrap' => FALSE,
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                    'crlf'      => "\r\n",
                    'newline'   => "\r\n",
                    'send_multipart' => FALSE
                    );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $records = $this->contact->getCompany();

        $this->email->from( $setmail, $records['CompanyName'] );
        $this->email->to( $to );
        $this->email->subject( $subject );
        $this->email->message( $html );
        $this->email->send();
      }

    }
```

From php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> PHP 5 allows developers to declare constructor methods for classes. Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each newly-created object, so it is suitable for any initialization that the object may need before it is used.

Comment: What is the name of this symbol : " -> " , and what is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html)

Theses methods are the constructors of your class.

Constructors are useful if you need to set some default values, or run a default process when your class is instantiated. Constructors can’t return a value, but they can do some default work.

If you intend to use a constructor in any of your Controllers, you MUST place the `__construct` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //predefined view,models,etc..,
      }
```

__construct function let's you define model,view,helper and other libraries, on the top of a class.
it's these model,views are belongs to that class 
so, you no need to be load these for each function you call or create
once it's create it's take care of the rest of your class.

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('your_model_name');
        $this->load->view('your_view_name');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

construct can be applied on the controller this will help you to load library and helper at once you don't need to rewrite on each method that you want to use it in order to reload them...! example where we can use the construct

> **at this line of code I show you where we can use it.**

```
<?php 
Class example extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library(array('session','form_validation'));
}

 public function useFile(){
   //here you don't need to reload your library and helper again just type your code 

}
?>
```

You will load library and helper at single Controller. We load these file to perform some of functionality like to get user data session, to add validation in form like to force user to fill all the input fiel required etc.

[You can read more about Contruct](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#class-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

1: Why do I need to use __construct()?
2: When should I use this function?
3: What is parent::__construct()?

1-Ans : The reason of using __Construct() is predefined and it is used in C.I as global to load any function

2-Ans : Best use of this function is as global .. just suppose if you want to load any model in function A, and function B and function C. So When you load the model then load it in Construct() and it works as Global and it loads in all functions.

3-Ans : Global to all functions

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are useful if you need to set some default values, or run a default process when your class is instantiated. Constructors can’t return a value, but they can do some default work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
   class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller {

      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper('url'); 
         $this->load->database(); 
      } 

      public function index() { 
         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 

         $this->load->helper('url'); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function add_student_view() { 
         $this->load->helper('form'); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_add'); 
      } 

      public function add_student() { 
         $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

         $data = array( 
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
            'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
         ); 

         $this->Stud_Model->insert($data); 

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function update_student_view() { 
         $this->load->helper('form'); 
         $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
         $query = $this->db->get_where("stud",array("roll_no"=>$roll_no));
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $data['old_roll_no'] = $roll_no; 
         $this->load->view('Stud_edit',$data); 
      } 

      public function update_student(){ 
         $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

         $data = array( 
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
            'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
         ); 

         $old_roll_no = $this->input->post('old_roll_no'); 
         $this->Stud_Model->update($data,$old_roll_no); 

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function delete_student() { 
         $this->load->model('Stud_Model'); 
         $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
         $this->Stud_Model->delete($roll_no); 

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Why do you think that it solves the problem?